# Joomla - Override bootstrap.min.css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, joomla3.0, joomla-template, overriding

Working on Joomla but don't want to use bootstrap...EVER. I created a CSS override with a blank `bootstrap.css` file in the `templates/mytemplate/css/bootstrap.css`. This worked, but doing the same thing for `bootstrap.min.css` does not work... any ideas?

I know I can just rename or delete the `media/jui/css` bootstrap css files, but this isn't a permanent solution since they get updated every time I update the Joomla version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found it. There were several ways to unset/ignore the CSS file, but only this one worked on my Joomla 3.4:

```
<?php
unset($this->_styleSheets[$this->baseurl .'/media/jui/css/bootstrap.min.css']);
?>
```